# Get foreign key table with a single query using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following two tables

```
Groups
- Id
- Name

Members
- Id
- GroupId
- Name
```

I want to display a list of Groups with their member count. I can get all the groups and then use a foreach statement to count the number of members. But this is very inefficient.

Is there a way to write a LINQ query that will return the member count in a single query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with a simple linq-to-entities query. You can either project it to an anonymous type or you can create your own class to store the information.

```
var query = from g in context.Groups
            join m in context.Members on g.Id equals m.GroupId into members
            select new 
            {
              Group = g,
              MemberCount = members.Count(),
            };
```

Comment: haven't tested it but is this valid?  Group = g

Comment: @James - Yes, or you can just select the properties you want like: `GroupId = g.Id, GroupName = g.Name, etc`

Answer (score 2):

If there are foreign key relationships, wouldn't this work?

```
var q = context.Groups.Select(x => new { Group = x.Name, Count = x.Members.Count() } );
```